# Remote ipython kernel not displaying inline matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I run an ipython kernel on a remote ubuntu server using:

```
ipython kernel --matplotlib inline
```

I then connect to it successfully on a second ubuntu machine using:

```
ipython qtconsole --existing XXX.json --ssh login@remoteserver
```

However, when I try to display an inline matplotlib plot, nothing appears. No error message is displayed, both on the server and client console. Matplotlib inline graph are displayed correctly when the console and kernel are running on the same machine.

Is there something I should do to make it work?

Comment: Don't use --pylab it is deprecated.

Comment: The problem is the same using --matplotlib inline. I edited my post.

Comment: maybe an export to the DISPLAY variable? can you use savefig() or does that  also fail ?

Comment: I tested, savefig() works fine, it seems only the inline remote graph have issues. Does a similar setup works for you?